# Join records from another table as JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, join

We have the two tables: "product" and "product_part".
One product can have many product parts, so that the product_part has `id_product` column that refernces a product's `id` column.

I would really like to create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` that from this data set:

```
| Product | Product Part|
+-----------------------+
| Gearbox | Metal scrap |
+-----------------------+
| Gearbox | Iron scrap  |
+-----------------------+
| Gearbox | Gold scrap  |
+-----------------------+
```

Would create this output:

```
| Product | Parts                                          |
+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| Gearbox | ["Metal scrap", "Iron scrap", "Gold scrap"]    |
+---------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would just be:

```
SELECT product.name, json_agg(product_part.name) as parts
FROM product
JOIN product_part ON product.id = product_part.product_id
GROUP BY product.id, product.name;
```

I had to guess a bit about your actual columns, but this should be close.

Comment: Thank you. I think I may use it nicely to optimize app when combined with materialized views.